How to define a two sided linear map from an hilbert bimodule to a $ C^* $ - algebra?
Let $X$ be an Hilbert $A-B$ - bimodule with $A$ and $B$ any two $C^*$-algebras.
Is there a homomorphism of hilbert $A-B$ - bimodules $ \varphi \ : \ X \to C $, with $C$ any different $C^*$-algebra from $A$ and $B$, where $f$ is linear with respect to $A$, and anti-linear with respect to $B$ ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Can’t you choose C to be anything and then just take $\varphi$ to be the zero function?

Thank you, but i need a non trivial exemple.

What exactly do you mean by linear w.r.t. $A$ and anti-linear w.r.t. $B$? Just $\phi(axb)=a\phi(x)b$?

I'm confused as well. Do you mean to construct, for any given Hilbert $A - B$-module $X$, a $C^\ast$-algebra $C$ which contains $A$ and $B$ as $C^\ast$-subalgebras and a $A - B$-bimodular map $\phi: X \to C$?

$ \phi ( x + ay ) = \phi (x) + a \phi (b) $, and, $ \phi ( x + yb ) = \phi (x) + \phi (y) \overline{b} $. I don't know if there is references which talk about that.

@David : I mean to construct, for any given Hilbert $A−B$-module $X$, a $C^∗$-algebra $C$ which contains $\phi(A)$ and $ \phi(B)$ as $C^∗$-subalgebras and a $A−B$-bimodular map $\phi : X \to C$.

What would $\bar b$ be there? If that's anti-linear in $b$, then that won't work.

On the other hand, I can answer the question as described in your last comment (without any kind of "anti-linearity").

@MaoWao, I only want to have some references which talk about $A-B$- bimodular maps between Hilbert bimodules. I don't find any book which treat this subject on the net unfortunately.

Now that's a completely different question again. Do you look for an answer to the question from your second-last comment or general references?

I want the two things in the same times @MaoWao.

Assume that $B$ is faithfully represented on $H$ and let $K$ be the Hilbert space obtained from the algebraic tensor product $X\odot H$ after separation and completion with respect to the following inner product:
$$
\langle x\otimes\xi,y\otimes\eta\rangle_K=\langle \xi,\langle x\vert y\rangle_B\eta\rangle_H.
$$
I will write $x\otimes_K\xi$ for the image of $x\otimes\xi$ in $K$. One can check that $xb\otimes_K\xi=x\otimes_K b\xi$ for all $x\in X$, $b\in B$, $\xi\in H$.
Let $\mathcal L(X_B)$ denote the adjointable operators on $X$. There is a representation $\pi$ of $\mathcal L(X_B)$ on $K$ given by
$$
\pi(T)(x\otimes_K\xi)=Tx\otimes_K\xi.
$$
Note that by definition, $A\subset \mathcal L(X_B)$. Moreover, we have a map $\varphi\colon X\to \mathbb B(H;K)$ given by $\varphi(x)\xi=x\otimes_K\xi$. This map is a bimodule map in the following sense:
$$
\varphi(axb)\xi=axb\otimes_K\xi=ax\otimes_K b\xi=\pi(a)\varphi(x)b\xi.
$$
Of course $\mathbb B(H;K)$ is not a $C^\ast$-algebra, but you can embed it into $\mathbb B(H\oplus K)$ in the upper right corner.
There is also a smaller $C^\ast$-algebra that is in a sense the more natural codomain: The linking algebra for $_A X_B$ is the the following $C^\ast$-algebra:
$$
C=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}b&\varphi(x)\\\varphi(y)^\ast&\pi(T)\end{pmatrix}:x,y\in X,b\in B,T\in\mathcal L(X_B)\right\}.
$$
The map $x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0&\varphi(x)\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ has all the properties you are looking for.

Thank you Sir MaoWao. It start to be clear for me now, but, can you give me some references which talk about bimodular maps between Hilbert bimodules ?

This guy maintains a reference list with more references than you'll probably ever read: https://www.imn.htwk-leipzig.de/~mfrank/hilmod.html. I don't know any books on the topic particularly well.

Thank you Sir. :-D
